# log4j2 JsonLayout standard fields

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

By default,
`JsonLayout` generates many helpful fields.
Unfortunately,
when I provide an additional
`KeyValuePair` in the configuration,
the log entry content is reduced to only the custom keys and
`"logEvent"`.

Configuration:

```xml
<JsonLayout objectMessageAsJsonObject="true"
            propertiesAsList="false"
            properties="true"
            locationInfo="false"
            includeStacktrace="true"
            compact="true"
            complete="false"
            eventEol="true">
    <!--KeyValuePair key="myKey" value="anything"/ -->
</JsonLayout>
```

When `KeyValuePair` is commented out,
the log entry looks like this:

```
{
    "thread": "main",
    "level": "INFO",
    "loggerName": "MainKt",
    "message": "Hello=10 World=20",
    "endOfBatch": false,
    "loggerFqcn": "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
    "threadId": 1,
    "contextMap": 
    {
        "test": "2"
    },
    "instant": 
    {
        "epochSecond": 1575310424,
        "nanoOfSecond": 747824500
    },
    "threadPriority": 5
}
```

When it is included in the config:

```
{"logEvent":"Hello=10 World=20","myKey":"anything"}
```

How do I include the default fields with my keyValue pairs?
I don't want them all,
only `level`, `markers`, `mdc`, `loggerName`, `threadId`.
Is there any map for this?
I don't see the answer in the docs.

Another part is `objectMessageAsJsonObject` behavior:
When no additional key is provided I see `message` with the JSON object in it,
but as soon as I provide any key it disappears and `logEvent` is populated
by any value from previous log (this feels like a bug to me).

Comment: Regarding the first part of fields disappearing when KVP added, seems like a bug in the latest version of log4j2, if I use version 2.11.1 it works as expected.

Comment: I have absolutely the same problem!

Comment: Do you have a bug link somewhere?